# Alternative to nested LinearLayouts?

Tags: android, xml, layout

A bird whispered in my ear that nested layouts should be avoided because of performance issues.

What I need is to place 6 circular buttons in a random position in a layout. Since absolutLayout is deprecated, my quick fix has been to nest LinearLayouts and place the childviews in either "TOP", "CENTER" or "BOTTOM" position (GravityFlags).

[image: For those who have a hard time visualising, I made an awesome paint.jpg explaning]

This is the closest I've come to randomly place buttons in a screen, but if anyone has a more convenient solution I'd love to here it. My xml for this layout is a mess.

Comment: `GridLayout` or `TableLayout`

Comment: It'll still be in very fixed positions. I want the closest to AbsoluteLayout.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean - Linear, Grid and Table layouts are very flexible as they support `weight`s, which means they will automatically adjust to the size of their container. `AbsoluteLayout` is one of the most fixed layouts, as it relies on "absolute positioning" - if you must define fixed dimensions for some reason, then simply use those in one of those above layouts, or in anything (i.e. `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`)

Comment: I want these six buttons to be randomly positioned everytime the Activity gets restarted. By fixed I meant (as in LinearLayout) that I can only set them to top, center or bottom and nothing in between either vertically or horizontally.

Comment: Ahh OK. Perhaps a FrameLayout then, if you want their positions to have the least constraints. Then you can just set the x/y coordinates of each circle programmatically.

Comment: Not sure how you were thinking but FrameLayout is best used for single childviews.

Comment: Most of the time that's true, but this case is unusual as you want to position items randomly